# dust.js -- template name introspection from a helper

Tags: dust.js

From a dust helper, how can I get the **template name** from which I'm called, eg:

```js
var compiled = dust.compile("hi, I'm the {@whoami/} template!", "hi.dust");
dust.loadSource(compiled);

// should assert true
dust.render("hi.dust", {}, function(er, out) {
  assert(out, "hi, I'm the hi.dust template!");
});
```

Help me with the `{@whoami}` helper so it asserts `true`:

```js
dust.helpers.whoami = function (chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var str = /* >>> HELP ME HERE <<< */;

  return chunk.write(str);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

templateName is put on the context, so you can just use `context.templateName` inside of your helper to access it.  In a future version of dust, it is likely this will change to `context.__templateName`, because we realized you won't be able to put a variable named templateName in your context, but for now you're good to go.